# Is it possible for a DFA to change its state to a new state without accepting any input symbol

Tags: finite-automata, automata, dfa

Is it possible for a DFA to change its state without accepting its state i.e-

```
for instance,

A(self loop of (a,b) over state A)--->B..........
```

**for input symbols - (a,b)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In computer science [epsilon transistions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton#NFA_with_.CE.B5-moves) are used for that. But you will usually get a NDFA, and you can always eliminate the epsilon transitions to obtain an equivalent automata without epsilon transitions.